# React start up problem with new react app windows [solved]

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hello i am not really sure how to explain my problem or how to ask for help.

But am going to try it anyway lately when i create a react app it installs like normal.
But from the moment i use npm start i get this error ([npm start error terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMr1b.png)).
Which says it has nothing wrong with node js/npm so i suspected it was something about the react app dependency that was wrong. When i downgrade to a older version of react scripts it works but the newest version 16.13.1 doesn't work even tho i use this version of react on my windows laptop. In case it helps to solve my issue here is the error log that npm generates ([error log npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVaqJ.png)) i hope this helps to solve my issue

Comment: are you generating it using npx or create-react-app cli ?

Comment: am using npx create-react-app to generate my react app which normally gives the latest version of all the dependencies

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution for my problem by setting the path value for system32.
You can do this by the following steps

Goto > Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advance system setting\Enviroment variable and set system variables path C:\Windows\System32\ variable and restart your System.

After i have done these steps it seems to work